# Using Array.splice removes strings from two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

So this is what I am dealing with:

At the top of the js file i declare these variables:

```
let teensArray = [];
let copyteensArray = [];
let teensArrayLength = 0;
let teensArrayPlayed = 0;

$.getJSON("json/teens.json", function(data) {
        teensArray = data.statements;
        copyteensArray = data.statements;
        teensArrayLength = data.statements.length;
        $(".teens .total-cards").text(teensArrayLength + " CARDS")
    });
```

Everytime the mode is "teens" this executes:

```
if (mode == "teens") {
        let currStatement = copyteensArray[getRandomInt(copyteensArray.length)]
        let index = copyteensArray.indexOf(currStatement)
        copyteensArray.splice(index, 1);
        currentPack = "TEENS PACK";
        currentColor = "#23B574";
        srcImg = "svg/007-party hat.svg"
        playedCardsText = ++teensArrayPlayed + " / " + teensArrayLength;
        console.log(copyteensArray.length);
        console.log(teensArray.length);
        return currStatement;
    }
```

The problem: The teensArray has the same values as copyteensArray after the if statement.

Example values:

***Before if statement***
teensArray["1","2","3","4"]
copyteensArray["1","2","3","4"]

***Inside if statement***
copyteensArray.splice(index, 1);

***After the return inside the if statement*** 
teensArray["1","3","4"]
copyteensArray["1","3","4"]

This function executes ONLY if the user decides to go back to another screen:

```
function reset() {
    copyteensArray = teensArray;
    teensArrayPlayed = 0;
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: I'd suspect that copyTeensArray and teensArray are pointing to the same object as a result of code not included in the snippet

Comment: @TedBrownlow I added a snippet, check it, but I doubt that it would be it?

Comment: "The `splice()` method changes the contents of an array by removing or replacing existing elements and/or adding new elements in place" in order to copy `teensArray` use `teensArray.slice()` before that

Comment: `copyteensArray = teensArray;` just points `copyteensArray` to `teensArray`. You'll need to either slice or spread: `copyteensArray = teensArray.slice();` or `copyteensArray = [...teensArray];` to return a new array. But keep in mind that while this will copy primitive elements, it will return references to any nested objects.

Comment: Sorry @pilchard, I forgot to add $.getJSON function in the snippet. Your solution doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Well in that snippet both `copyTeens` and `teens` are references to `data.statements` so once again, `slice()` or `[...spread]`

Comment: @pilchard & @zb22, thank you for the help. Yes, that was correct, I tried with `teensArray = data.statements;  copyteensArray = teensArray.slice();` and it works, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`copyteensArray = teensArray;` makes the same pointer point to both of them. Consider using `copyteensArray = [...teensArray];` which assigns brand new instance of `teensArray` content to `copyteensArray`

Answer (score 1):

You have a "shallow" copy of the array, ie both the array point to the same objects. Any changes made to the shallow copy will change the original object.

You can visualize it as a shortcut in Windows. Whatever change you make to the shortcut also changes the original object.

Solve this making a hard copy. There are multiple ways in ES6 to do that.

```
hardCopy = [...OriginalArray];
```

And another way is to JSON.stringify() the object and parse it back.

```
hardCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(OriginalArray));
```

For your code, fix this by changing these lines

```
$.getJSON("json/teens.json", function(data) {
        teensArray = [...data.statements];
        copyteensArray = [...data.statements];
```